# How to download photos attached to a message sent to my Telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, photo, php-telegram-bot

The `Message` object has a `photo` field, which contains an array of `PhotoSize` objects. And everything is in order if one photo was sent to the bot, because you can take just the last item. But if several photos are sent, then getting the largest photo is no longer possible. How to download the largest copy of each photo?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take the time to read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in order to understand how to post a good question so that the community can assist you. Please edit your post and add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and any errors or logs you might get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no logic here:

`if several photos are sent, then getting the largest photo is no longer possible`

If album (or just some photos) were sent to a bot, it will get as many updates with separate `Message` object as many photos were sent.

It means, that you need to take the last element of `PhotoSize` array every time and you will have the largest photo in this case.